# How to set required atribute on CSS modified radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I have a form where i have groups of 5 radiobuttons and i set the required atribute  on the first radio button. This allows me to use jquery.validate.js before submitting the form via jquery.form.js.

i want to use images instead of the browser standard radio buttons

i use the following CSS

```
input[type='radio']{
display:none;
}

input[type='radio']+span:before{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url(images/radiobutton_off.png) no-repeat center bottom;
background-size: 28px 28px;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+span:before{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url(images/radiobutton_on.png) no-repeat center bottom;
background-size: 28px 28px;
}

input[type='radio']:hover+span:before{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url(images/radiobutton_on.png) no-repeat center bottom;
background-size: 28px 28px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

label{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

And i change the `<input type=radio name=c$row_2[0] value='0' $sel0[$w] required>`

to

```
<label><input type=radio name=c$row_2[0] value='0' $sel0[$w] required><span></span></label>
```

this works excelent for styling the radiobuttons, but the required atribute is not captured by jquery.validate.js

How can i assign the required atribute to CSS styled image radio buttons.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Use different css that doesn't require `display:none`. Can make the label overflow hidden and offset the radio position instead

Comment: Check out the [`ignore`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) option. As of version 1.9.0, it defaults to `:hidden`.

Comment: @showdev thanks for pointing it out, ignore works fine!!!